# Should I give water to my melocactus in winter?

Tags: watering, cactus

I live in Riverside, California, USA, an arid environment, and have two melocactus plants: *azureus* & *matazanus*.  Reading tips on their care I find that they are 'winter dormant' and water should be withheld. Also, and kind of contradictory, that the roots may die if not watered.

Since the night temperatures have been below 50 degrees F (10 C) I'v brought them inside and provided grow lights; they have not received any water for 2 months or more.  They will go outside when nighttime temperatures are above 10C.

Should I withhold water until 'spring' or give them a drink?  If I should give them a drink, how often should it be?